# css sticky nested div container

Tags: html, css

I have simple html structure with left menu and content in right section and I want to left container submenu-2 sticked to the top after scroll to down. I use position:sticky and top:0px but it not working

Why this solutions is not working, how I can fix this?

```css
#big {}

#left {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

#left .submenu-1 {
  border: 1px solid #8b8b8b;
}

#left .submenu-2 {
  border: 1px solid #8b8b8b;
  top: 0px;
  position: sticky;
}

#content {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="big">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="submenu-1">
      submenu 1<br/>
      <br/><br/><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu-2">
      submenu 2<br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
    with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it?
    <br/><br/> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using
    'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
    Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    <br/><br/> Where does it come from?
    <br/><br/> Where does it come from?
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out [this example](https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/9897) using jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Sticky is incompatible with floats. Use flex instead. And just in case you were wondering, flex perorms better than grid, here's a benchmark test: https://techblog.smc.it/en/2020-08-03/grid-vs-flexbox-performance

```css
#big {
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  width: 20%;
  top: 0px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

#left .submenu-1 {
  border: 1px solid #8b8b8b;
}

.submenu-2 {
  border: 1px solid #8b8b8b;
  top: 0px;
  position: sticky;
}

#content {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div id="big">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="submenu-1">
      submenu 1<br/>
      <br/><br/><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu-2">
      submenu 2<br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
    with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it?
    <br/><br/> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using
    'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
    Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    <br/><br/> Where does it come from?
    <br/><br/> Where does it come from?
    <br/><br/> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using
    'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
    Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    <br/><br/> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using
    'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
    Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    <br/><br/> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using
    'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
    Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    <br/><br/> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using
    'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
    Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The referenced benchmark is not relevant: 10000 elements is not realistic and can encounter other browser inefficiencies outside of flexbox/grid, the elements are added dynamically, and the layout is not fixed width as is the question here. Furthermore, the author of the benchmark shows that they both perform the same on complex layouts, and highlights how much easier grids are than flexbox (less developer time). CSS grid can outperform flexbox on fixed width columns - using the same benchmark proves this: https://codesandbox.io/s/css-grid-vs-flexbox-performance-evaluation-forked-ys1ce

Comment: @RyanWheale - We're splitting hairs with benchmarking flex versus grid, are we not? The amount of css and js in your app will trump these measurements. I never heard of someone switching from flex to grid to make their app perform better. LOL

Comment: I know - but you included an invalid benchmark in your answer, which you only added after I posted my answer. I assumed the responsibility of pointing out the flaws in the benchmark and that the benchmark could be twisted to show that grids are indeed faster in a situation which more closely resembles the OP's situation.

Comment: @RyanWheale I saw you editing you answer. LOL. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using CSS grids and getting rid of the floats. Grids are also much better than flexbox for top-level layout as it's more rigid requires less calculation for the browser (slightly better rendering performance). Everything will work as expected, and your CSS won't look like it came from 2005 ;).

```css
#big { 
  /* add this */
  display: grid;
  gap: 5%;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 70%;
}

#left {
  /* remove float and width */
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

#left .submenu-1 {
  border: 1px solid #8b8b8b;
}

#left .submenu-2 {
  border: 1px solid #8b8b8b;
  top: 0px;
  position: sticky;
}

#content {
  /* remove float and width */
}
```

```html
<div id="big">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="submenu-1">
      submenu 1<br/>
      <br/><br/><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu-2">
      submenu 2<br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
    with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it?
    <br/><br/> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using
    'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
    Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    <br/><br/> Where does it come from?
    <br/><br/> Where does it come from?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this, have the main div #big as a flex box.
```

```css
#big {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

#left {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="big">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="submenu-1">
      submenu 1<br/>
      <br/><br/><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu-2">
      submenu 2<br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
    with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it?
    <br/><br/> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using
    'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
    Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    <br/><br/> Where does it come from?
    <br/><br/> Where does it come from?
  </div>
</div>
```